# why marginBottom not working?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/messageLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/messageSender"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageSenderName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/messageSender"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text_color"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messageContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/messageSender"
        android:layout_below="@id/messageSenderName"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/codeFont"
        android:textSize="13dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my layout I have problem. When I set `marginTop="5dp"` it's fine, but when I use `marginBottom` nothing happens in my layout. Also when I set padding in `RelativeLayout` it does not work either. What is the problem here? Could you give me any solution?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`marginBottom` has no effect if you set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `<RelativeLayout>`, instead set it as **match_parent** and check.

Comment: `fill_parent` is deprecated starting in API Level 8 and replaced by `match_parent`.

Comment: @RosePerrone yes I know but I think this answer is posted 2 years back ;)

Comment: No need to update..it make sense..how many ans one can update then ?

Comment: Seems fixed in API 19+.

Answer (score 19):

It is realy just a bug of the `<RelativeLayout>`, so you could try to wrap the RelativeLayout inside of a `<LinearLayout>` and set the margin there.

Comment: just change the relative for a linear if it is posible.

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure in which revision of android you are experiencing this issue. I looked at RelativeLayout in Android 4.2.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.2.2_r1.1/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java) and I believe there is a bug in the onMeasure.

In lines 486 to 488, we have following code:

```
if (isWrapContentHeight) {
    height = Math.max(height, params.mBottom);
}
```

In my opinion, the above should read:

```
if (isWrapContentHeight) {
    height = Math.max(height, params.mBottom + params.bottomMargin);
}
```

With android:layout_height="wrap_content", RelativeLayout does not appear take into account the bottomMargin of the last vertically laid out view.

I suggest you try one of the following:

*) Add a dummy view that will be the very last vertically laid out view, and ensure that it has the android:layout_below attribute. Note that the dummy view does not have a bottom margin, it is there so that RelativeLayout considers the bottom margin of views laid out above it. For your case, the dummy view would look like this:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/messageSender"
/>
```

*) As others have mentioned, achieve the same effect in other ways, such as Padding.

*) A not-so-trivial solution is bring in RelativeLayout, its platform style definitions and Pool management classes into your project, perform the bug fix I mentioned above and use this anywhere you would normally use RelativeLayout.

*) File a bug with Google

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest versions of `RelativeLayout`, but it now depends on the target SDK version you are using. In `Android 5.1.1`, it is done by checking the version like this: `if (targetSdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        height = Math.max(height, params.mBottom);
                    } else {
                        height = Math.max(height, params.mBottom + params.bottomMargin);
                    }`, see line 502 - 508 here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r1/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you can set `android:paddingBottom=""` of `<RelativeLayout>` to get the same effect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Naveen I don't know:)

Comment: This is an acceptable work around for an otherwise incomprehensible misgiving.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `layout_height` of your root container is set to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: How can I possibly change it to `match_parent` when it has to be `wrap_content` - it's a huge difference in the rest of the layout !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had a `<View>` inside a `<RelativeLayout>` and the `marginBottom` on that view did not work. I found out that my chain of **`layout_below`** was broken, so therefore it makes sense that the layout did not know from which view the margin should be calculated.

If you **chain it properly using `layout_below`** or the other positioning tools, you do not need to worry about `wrap_content` or `match_parent` like others are suggesting. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/separator">

        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In some case you have lots of attributs or you just missed that you included earlier :

```
android:layout_margin="xdp"
```

You can't use it with specific layout margination

Answer (score -2):

It works if you use `android:layout_marginBottom with  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

For example :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
```

Comment: No, it doesn't, the problem is the layout_height="wrap_content"