# Margin from top Doesn't working with RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 5 button with an ImageView inside RelativeLayout and giving some margin to each of view from the top. But margin from top does not working in my condition.
My code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <fragment
            android:name="motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.model.splash.view.fragment.FragmentHeaderLineColor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:tag="@string/fragment_header"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </fragment>

    </LinearLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageCar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/mu7"/>

                <motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.util.custom.ButtonBold
                    android:id="@+id/btnJointInsp"
                    style="@style/ButtonTextMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageCar"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/menuJointInsp" />

                <motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.util.custom.ButtonBold
                    android:id="@+id/btnVehRec"
                    style="@style/ButtonTextMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnJointInsp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
                    android:text="@string/menuVehicleRec" />

                <motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.util.custom.ButtonBold
                    android:id="@+id/btnRecIns"
                    style="@style/ButtonTextMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnVehRec"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/menuRecIns" />

                <motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.util.custom.ButtonBold
                    android:id="@+id/btnPdi"
                    style="@style/ButtonTextMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnRecIns"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/menuPDI" />

                <motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.util.custom.ButtonBold
                    android:id="@+id/btnLocation"
                    style="@style/ButtonTextMenu"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnPdi"
                    android:background="@drawable/vehicle_list"
                    android:text="@string/menuLocation" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center">

        <fragment
            android:name="motorpool.orbitsysindia.com.motorpool.model.splash.view.fragment.FragmentFooter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_footer" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any kind of help is Appreciated by me:

Answer (score 1):

```
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header">
```

Please remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` from this relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Problem **[android:layout_alignParentTop](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentTop)**

> If true, makes the top edge of this view match the top edge of the
>   parent. Accommodates top margin.

You should remove **`android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`** property .

**EDIT**

> It is really just a bug of the RelativeLayout, so you could try to
>   wrap the RelativeLayout inside of a  LinearLayout and set the margin
>   there.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642071/why-marginbottom-not-working/15360874#15360874)** .

Comment: @Champandorid change above `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Thanks for you precious time but I didn't understand which LinearLayout ?

Comment: @Champandorid `android:id="@+id/header"` I assume its a Fragment